# Rewriting a logical statement with multiple quantifiers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I am currently reading "Discrete Mathematics with Applications" by Susanna Epp. Not all questions have answers in this book. I stumbled upon question 11 from Section 3.3

Let $S$ be the set of students at your school, let $M$ be the set of movies that have ever been released, and let $V(s,m)$ be "student $s$ have seen movie $m$." Rewrite the following statement without the symbol $\forall$, the symbol $\exists$, or variables.

$\exists{s} \in S$ and $\exists{t} \in S$ such that $ s \neq t$ and $\forall{m} \in M, V(s,m) \rightarrow V(t,m)$

I interpreted this as **"There are two students who watched all released movies"**. Is it right? If yes why do we need an if-then operator? If not what is the correct way?

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong but I think the correct interpretation is **"There are two distinct students such that if student $s$ has seen the movie $m$ then student $t$ has also seen $m$"**.

Comment: @amWhy I copied the question exactly as-is from the book. Indeed we are not supposed to use any quantifiers and variables, just pure sentences.

Comment: @Salieri'sNeighbor The book asks not to use any variables. It should be rewritten in informal language.

Comment: The correct statement is: “There are two distinct students, one of whom has seen all of the movies that the other has seen.”

Comment: Well if I'm correct then you can write it as **"There are two distinct students such that if a student has seen a movie then the other student has also seen that movie"**.

Comment: @amWhy actually Mark's and Salieri's answers seem correct. Perhaps, I didn't explain it well. By quantifiers, the question means not to use the symbols $\forall$ and $\exists$. However, the translations can be used such as "There are".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I expressed in the comments, your interpretation is not correct. **"There are two distinct students such that if a certain student has seen a movie then the other student has also seen that movie"** is correct. Your error probably came from thinking that $\forall m \in M$ meant that the students saw all the movies in existence. Rather, try to think of it as a "for any" than a "for all".  The if-else means that if one student has seen the movie, the other student has seen it too, and this is valid for any movie in existence.

**EDIT:** I tried making it more clear that is only a one-way conditional, instead of a biconditional, but Mark Saving's phrase **“There are two distinct students, one of whom has seen all of the movies that the other has seen.”** is much more clear than mine.